# Python dictionary to C++ map

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

I am very new to C++ and am trying to translate a dictionary into a C++ format. I can't quite seem to find the answer I am looking for from the previous questions submitted on here.

I have code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<string, int> BasePairMap;

int main()
{
    BasePairMap m;

    m['power'] = 0;
    m['select'] = 1;
    m['backup'] = 2;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    m['rewind'] = 71;
    m['boxoffice'] = 240;
    m['sky'] = 241;


    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting character overflow errors. How can I map string/int pairs together in C++?

Thanks

Comment: String in C++ use double quotes, have you tried changing your simple quotes to those?

Comment: C++ doesn't use `'` and `"` interchangeably. They are use to define different types of literals.

Comment: thank you both. that sorted my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While many languages (such as Python) allow developers to use either single or double quotes for strings, in C++ you need to use double quotes ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)). Simple quotes are used for the `char` type which describes a single character ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal)).

So your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<string, int> BasePairMap;

int main()
{
    BasePairMap m;

    m["power"] = 0;
    m["select"] = 1;
    m["backup"] = 2;
    // ...
    m["rewind"] = 71;
    m["boxoffice"] = 240;
    m["sky"] = 241;

    return 0;
}
```